# What is the process of awarding the Sportsmanship badge on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, badges, voting

W.K.T, Sportsmanship is the badge awarded to users when they up voted 100 answers on questions where an answer of them has a positive score.

I can see some of the users gained this badge without posting 100 answers. How is it possible?

See [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410342/zzzz) (sorry to point out; it's only as example), who has posted 68 answers and more than 30 answers has not scored any votes.

Even 0 is considered as a positive score, there are only 68 answers, this badge needs 100.

Some of his anwers' questions like [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263896/joomla-2-5-6-extention-to-poll-youtube-channel-videos-and-their-comments/12263966#12263966) [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437227/how-to-hide-src-folder-from-eclipse-project-explorer/14437600#14437600) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703584/need-to-use-htmls-tag-map-in-joomla-site/10785625#10785625) have only one answer.

If that posts' competetive answers got deleted and this user deleted his 32 upvoted answers, then only it's possible for this badge.

What is the process of awarding Sportsmanship badge in Stack Overflow?

Comment: A question can have answers from several users?

Comment: I'd guess he's upvoted several answers to the same question, where he has an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Say you post 20 answers, on questions that each have 6 answers (including yours).

You then upvote all other answers.

Presto - 100 upvoted competing answers, though one only has 20.

Comment: Does [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186450/186599) answer correct?

Comment: @Azik - Positive in this context is indeed > 0.

Comment: Which answer is correct for [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188522/what-will-happen-to-reputations-when-a-post-turns-back-to-normal-post-from-c-w) question?

Comment: @Azik - both are.

Comment: So, Vigbyor's answer is correct(ie, clicking on the upvote again after the post become non-wiki will gain the reps), in Aditya's case the posts were not get clicked upvote again(which were upvoted at C.W stage)

Comment: am I correct?..