# What will happen to my reputation when the Community Wiki status of a post is reversed?

Tags: support, reputation, voting, community-wiki, moderation

A per the Community Wiki [description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/186599),

> The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their
>   post entered community mode.
>
> The original author can flag the post to moderator attention for
>   re-convert the C.W to normal post, the moderators will take action on
>   that.

If the Community Wiki status of a post is reversed, what will happen to the reputation of votes (Up/down) gained by the post at during its time as a Community Wiki?

Comment: AFAICT when wiki is undone, it's as if it never happened. So after a recalc, all those votes that came in the middle will be counted.

Comment: Both the answers are differ from each other(personal experience), looks like mods should answer.

Comment: I take back my comment. I recently observed this. The votes cast during wiki have no effect.

Comment: Just to confirm what others said, backed up by me being a dev... If your post gained rep during CW, it belongs to the Community user. It can suck, but that's how the system works.

Comment: @Oded FWIW it seems to stop sucking like that [since June 2014](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233945/165773): "we're going to automatically recalculate the author's reputation when community wiki status is removed from a post."

Answer (score 8):

The votes that were cast in between the period (CW to non-CW) do not have any effect on reputation even after the post is converted to non-CW.

This has happened with me twice and I am saying this from experience. The two questions were:

- On MSO - [Rename "Very Low Quality" Flag as "Unsalvageably Bad"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181166/rename-very-low-quality-flag-as-unsalvageably-bad)
- On Ask Ubuntu - [Problem resolving many of the Web Pages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229274/problem-resolving-many-of-the-web-pages)

Answer (score 6):

When post is converted to C.W. its votes ( upvote/downvote ) doesn't increment or decrements the current reputation.

Once the post is return to normal post from C.W. all the votes remains same. But if the person who has voteup/votedown the same post, click on the voting icon again then for that person's vote the reputation gets changed as +10 or -2.  Meaning if I upvoted a C.W. post then during that time period that user's reputation doesnt increase to +10 but when that post converted to normal post and If I again click the upvote icon then that user get +10.

<sub><sub>Based on personal experience.</sub></sub>