# Regain "lost" reputation upon Community Wiki reversal

Tags: feature-request, reputation, community-wiki

My post on Stack Overflow was automatically turned into a Community Wiki, the rules of which I was not aware of before. This seems to have happened because it was edited more than ten times by me. The edits had a valid reason, and the post was flagged to undo its Community Wiki status, which a moderator indeed did.

After almost one day's heavy work with the OP, it was accepted as the correct answer while in the Community Wiki state. With this state reverted, the relevant reputation, i.e. upvotes and answer selection after becoming CW, seems to be lost. I have tried to wait for several hours to check if this is just a latency issue, but it does not seem to be so.

I was looking for similar threads on Meta, and found these:

- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)
- There was another one, which I cannot find right now. Sorry about that.

Would it be possible to implement a feature which makes it possible to either not lose or reclaim the reputation?

Comment: See ["What will happen to my reputation when the Community Wiki status of a post is reversed?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188522/what-will-happen-to-my-reputation-when-the-community-wiki-status-of-a-post-is-re). Not much can be done here. Any votes or other actions taken while a post is under Community Wiki status carry no reputation gain, even after the status is reversed.

Comment: Agree it's not a dupe, as this one here is now a feature request asking to "refund" the reputation once post is unwikified.

Comment: Voted to reopen as well, and I tried to clarify it a bit. It seems to be a reasonable request. If a moderator figures that the edits are fair enough to see CW status reversed, then the argument that the rep is deserved as well does not seem to be a strange one.

Comment: Does a reputation recalc not help?

Comment: @Johannes: does it?

Answer (score -2):

I think you might get the reputation back sometime in the future.

A similar thing happened to me. I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744807/gcm-device-registration-issue-in-android/15749554#15749554) from my phone, and accidentally checked the community wiki checkbox.

I flagged the answer and asked to unwiki it, but it was accepted while it was still community wiki. I thought the rep was lost, but a long time later - I think it was over a month - I noticed that I gained unexpected rep, and when I checked my rep changes history,  I found that I got the rep for that accepted answer.

There's still hope for you :-)

Comment: It is more likely it was unaccepted and accepted again.  Actions while the answer was CW should never earn rep, even months later

Comment: @psubsee2003 Well, the question was answered on `Apr 1 at 18:46`. I flagged it on `Apr 1 at 18:48`. It was accepted on `Apr 2 at 6:17`, and when I look at my reputation history, it shows as if I got the rep for it on `Apr 2 at 6:17`. However, I'm sure I didn't get it at the time, but a long time later. I think I got it due to some rep re-calculation. Beside my helpful flag asking to un-wiki the answer, I can't find an evidence of it ever being a community wiki (there's no edit history), so I don't know when it was un-wiki-ed.

Comment: @Eran [Here you go.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15749554/revisions) I just constructed the link manually.

Comment: @michaelb958 Thanks! So, the wiki status was removed at `Apr 2 at 11:17`, after the answer was already accepted, which proves I couldn't have gotten the rep when it was accepted.

Comment: You got 3 regular upvotes [yielding +30 rep after April 2nd](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15744807/timeline). (And it was not unaccepted/re-accepted like @psubsee2003 suggested.) Are you sure you got +2 rep for getting the answer accepted? You can easily search your own reputation by post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

Comment: @Arjan As I said in the first comment, I got +15 for the answer being accepted (you can see it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2013-09-09%2012:21:25Z&page=5), and it was accepted while it was community wiki. I never mentioned the upvotes rep, since I got them after it was un-wikied.

Comment: This happened to me once. I flaged for un-CW, and I gained 20 rep with the message "community wiki removed" or something like that.