# I accidentally made my post community wiki

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748067/console-read-doesnt-allow-me-to-input-anything-the-second-time/19748122#19748122) and found out that the answer was community wiki. I checked revision history and found out the answer was made community wiki by me (which I must have done accidentally). I was about to flag the post for a moderator to remove it from community wiki till I saw that the answer has been accepted.

My question is what is the use of bothering moderators to remove the post from community wiki. Will I still get the 15 rep for accept?

Comment: I don't think so - but you'd get +10 for every future upvote

Comment: Don't think there's much harm in flagging it for mod attention.

Comment: See [What will happen to my reputation when the Community Wiki status of a post is reversed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188522)